# Numpy 3D Array dimensions and slicing

Tags: numpy

I have trouble understanding the Numpy representation for 3D arrays. I'm used to it being (rows,columns,depth) but with Numpy it seems to be (depth,rows,columns).

E.g.:

```
c = np.arange(12)
c = c.reshape(2,3,2)
d = c
d = d.reshape(2,2,3)

print(c)
print(d)

[[[ 0  1]
  [ 2  3]
  [ 4  5]]

 [[ 6  7]
  [ 8  9]
  [10 11]]]
```

d:

```
[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]]

 [[ 6  7  8]
  [ 9 10 11]]]
```

d is the representation I wish for. Now if I want to access the second 2D array I can write:

```
print(d[1,:,:])

[[ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]]
```

So why is the representation so unintuitive for Numpy? And how would I access all uneven indexed(the first,3th,5th ...) 2D arrays of a 3D array given both representations?

Comment: The names are just a convenience; they aren't built in to the code.  In `numpy` the last dimension varies fastest (is inner most); MATLAB does the reverse. So the display breaks the array into blocks or planes on the first dimension.  But there isn't much difference in calculation speed.  `np.dstack` joins arrays on a 3rd, last axis (that's 'd'` for depth).

Comment: I don't know what you mean by uneven indexed 2d arrays.  In your example the first dimension is 2, and none is larger than 3.

Comment: @hpaulj in the (depth,row,column) example say I have a 9x3x3 array I want to get the 2D arrays that have an uneven index e.g. the 2D array that is at depth 1,3,5 and so on. Then I would write: c[0:10:2,:,:]. Begin,End,step but how would i get the same result with the other representation(row,column,depth).

Comment: `arr[1::2, :, :]` to get a subset of those depths.

Comment: You can transpose axes, e.g. `arr.transpose(1,2,0)` puts the depth dimension last.

Comment: Images often are stored with the 3 or 4 size color dimension last (inner most), so the first 2 dimensions represent the pixels.